# postgresql from group by table to another table with arrays

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I calculate data with simple group by as in for example

```
select formation,nsf_3,count(*) as number
from table a
group by formation,nsf_3
```

This query returns

```
formation   nsf_3       number 
CAP         PRODUCTION  2 
CAP         SERVICES    5
```

I want to use that information to put the data in another table with this structure

```
measure  list_values_dimensions  list_dimensions
      2  ['CAP','PRODUCTION']    ['formation','nsf_3']
      5  ['CAP','SERVICES']      ['formation','nsf_3']
```

Is there a simple way to do it in SQL (I use PostgreSQL) or do I have to write code outside SQL (I use Python and raw SQL with SQLAlchemy).

Answer (score 0):

```
with get_numbers as (
  select formation, nsf_3, count(*) as number
    from table a
   group by formation, nsf_3
)
select number as measure, 
       array[formation, nsf_3] as list_values_dimensions,
       array['formation', 'nsf_3'] as list_dimensions
  from get_numbers
;
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir. It is exactly what I needed and since I don't have your level of expertise on the subject it would have taken me a long time to figure that out by myself.

Comment: @loic_midy FYI, you do not need to do this in two steps if you do not need the intermediate result of `(formation, nsf_3, number)`.